# How to associate variable in array result

Tags: java, arrays

I'm studying Java basics from the beginning. But there is still some theoretical basis.

How do I calculate the average of each student in the example below?

```
    package teste01classes;

    public class Metodos {

        static void Media(Alunos[] aluno) {
            // SEE HERE.
            double[] media;
            for (int i = 0; i < aluno.length; i++) {
                media[i] = (aluno[i].n1 + aluno[i].n2 + aluno[i].n3) / 3;
                System.out.println(aluno[i].nome + media[i]);
            }
        }
    }



package teste01classes;

// Classe Alunos com os campos
public class Alunos {
    String nome;
    int n1, n2, n3;
}



package teste01classes;

public class Teste01Classes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Alunos[] aluno = DadosAlunos.createAlunos();

    }
}
```

Comment: in your `main` method, aren't you missing `Metodos.Media(aluno);`? Also, you should read up on Java naming conventions...you are violating several of them, which makes your code difficult to read.

Comment: The is Metodos.Media(aluno) or Metodos.media(aluno)?

Comment: camel case your methods (e.g. `fooBar()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to *initialize* the `media` [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html), and then `return` it:

```
static double[] media(Alunos[] aluno) {
  // allocate memory for a double array of size aluno.length
  double[] media = new double[aluno.length];
  for (int i = 0; i < aluno.length; i++) {
    media[i] = (aluno[i].n1 + aluno[i].n2 + aluno[i].n3) / 3;
    System.out.println(aluno[i].nome + media[i]);
  }
  return media;
}
```

Then, in your `main`, invoke it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Alunos[] aluno = DadosAlunos.createAlunos();
  double[] medias = Metodos.media(aluno);
}
```

Comment: João how to return 4.67, for example? int n1, n2, n3 convert to double?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Divide by `3.0d` instead.